# Trying to get bound for an integral of difference of two functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $f$ be a smooth function, non-negative i.e. $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$, with compact support such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) dx = 1$
Let $z$ be a real number and $n$ a natural number.
I would like to get an upper bound for
$$
I(z, n) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(\frac{z}{n} + x) - f(\frac{z}{n-1} + x)| dx
$$
. If the absolute value was not there, then the integral would be $0$.
How well can I bound this with the presence of absolute value? than you

Comment: For any $f$, $z$, $n$ there is only one value of integral. You need to find upper bound for integral among all possible $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a fixed $f$ and a fixed $z$, how does $I(z,n)$ behave?

Let $f(x)=0$ on $x\in(-\infty,r)\bigcup(s,\infty)$.

Let $k(d)=\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(x+d)-f(x)|$.

You have $|I(z,n)|\leq(s-r+\frac{|z|}{n(n-1)})\times k\bigg(\frac{z}{n(n-1)}\bigg)$.

A mere piecewise linear function (or you can modify it to make it smooth, as your conditions demand) shows that this is asymptotically the best bound possible.

Comment: my apologies. I added a fix

Comment: @JohnnyT. the part of the answer I am keeping here still applies